# Prime Numbers in a given range without using flag

Tags: java

I am New To Programming in Java.
I want to print prime numbers in a given range.
I know that flag method but i want to try something else.

i worked on this method .

/**
 *
 * @author Mridul
 */
public class JavaApplication23 {

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    int x1=2;
    int x2=89;

    for(int i=x1;i<x2;i++)
    {
        for(int j=2;j<i;j++)
        {
            if(i%j==0)
            {
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(i);


        }

    }
}
}
```

Its not giving me the desired result.
Can anybody edit this code so i can get the result 
Please dont use any new variable, just edit this code.

Comment: We won't. Describe where you are stuck

Comment: Welcome to SO. Generally a statement like 'can anybody edit this code' will be interpreted on this site as asking us to do your work for you. I suggest that you explain what results you are seeing, what results you expect to see and anything you have done to investigate (e.g. debugging).... or wait a few minutes until someone points out the problem so you can avoid learning anything :-)

Comment: Ah didn't take a few minutes after all!

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i=x1;i<x2;i++)
{
    int factors = 0;
    for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
    {
        if(i%j==0)
        {
            factors++;
        }
    }
    if(factors == 2)
      System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: i dont want to create any new variable, just use that code and edit it

Comment: @Mridul - see my comment below (on one of the answers) regarding optimization.  Realize your statement amounts to "I don't want  optimal code"

Comment: i will do the optimization late, 
here i want to do something new 
so please can you edit my current code to give me the desired result

Comment: new, in what way - your current (with your limited variable set) isn't working.  If the solution is an additional variable, are you not just refusing any solution?  Or are you stuck in an assumption that it is POSSIBLE using the existing set?

Comment: How do you expect to "modify" wrong code without essentially making any changes ?

Comment: @John Yes i think it is possible with current set just by using some more if ,for loops so i want to get the answer.

Comment: @skb by using more loops(for,if)

Comment: @Mridul - so you want to worsen the optimization???? (what would happen with the additional loops and checks/ifs)

Comment: @skb - note: you'd have to lose the factors++, the method optimizes by only checking one of the pair, so factors would NEVER be 2.

Comment: So in a nutshell  you don't want to add a single variable but are ready to add as many for loops and if blocks as possible ?

Comment: @John ah you're right, didn't think about the rest of the code when I made the square root change earlier. I'll change it in a sec.

Comment: @skb - in other words, a thought exercise - not intended to produce any usable code.  Although, if that is the case, and as x1, x2 are given, a simple if /else if structure checking for 2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,83 and 89 would do it - problem solved - all ifs, no loops :) (well, except for the main loop)

Comment: I am trying an Experiment guys, its just an experiment to figure out if i can get the result in this manner. Please dont mock me for this. I am just a beginner

Comment: @skb - yes no new variable..i repeat its just an experiment

Comment: @MridulMittal it's perfectly alright ! We all were at this stage at some point or the other. I decided to revert back code to the original form (without the optimizations suggested by John) just so that it becomes less complicated and you could focus on the logic better.

Comment: @skb thanks
i already understand this logic and also that flag logic,
all i am trying is to create my own logic which i feel should work with some edit in the code i have written

Comment: @MridulMittal a general piece of advice : Here at Stack Overflow people prefer to the point specific questions. State your problem, show what you've already tried, and ask in clear wordings what exactly do you want to know, and you'll fare well :).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     // TODO code application logic here
     int x1=2;
     int x2=89;

     for(int i=x1;i<x2;i++)
     {
         boolean prime = true;
         for(int j=2;j<i;j++)
         {
             if(i%j==0)
             {   
                 prime = false;
                 break;
             }

         }
         if (prime) {
             System.out.println(i);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Spoon-feeding isn't always a bad thing for new people, but when it's a question like this, where the author values our time so little that he/she didn't even give a sample expected output vs actual output, then I really think people should just ignore it. However, I understand why people don't as, typically, they're pretty easy questions to answer.

Comment: i have written i want prime numbers as the output but its not giving me.
and i dont want to use any new variable.

Answer (score 0):

How is this? (Written from my phone, i hope it works)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int x1=2;
  int x2=89;
  for(int i=x1;i<x2;i++) {
    boolean isPrime = true;
    for(int j=2;j<i;j++) {
      if(i%j==0) {
        isPrime = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    if(isPrime) {
      System.out.println(i);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks but i dont want to use any new variable, just edit that code only

Comment: minor note for optimization, you do not need to check for j < i, you need to check ONLY for j < k, where k = round( sqrt ( i ) ). NOTE: placed in separate variable to do calculation only once for any given i